# subprocess - startupinfo - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

i have tried to run this code

```
filepath = "C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test/Audio/"     #Input audio file path


from pydub import AudioSegment
import os

def mp3_to_wav(audio_file_name):
    if audio_file_name.split('.')[1] == 'mp3':    
        sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_file_name)
        audio_file_name = audio_file_name.split('.')[0] + '.wav'
        sound.export(audio_file_name, format="wav")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for audio_file_name in os.listdir(filepath): 
        file_name = filepath + audio_file_name
        file_name = os.path.realpath(file_name)
        mp3_to_wav(file_name)
```

but i got this error below (last line)

```
runfile('C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test/test2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test')
C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:193: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b871056654c0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test/test2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test')

  File "C:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test/test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    mp3_to_wav(file_name)

  File "C:/Users/Linus/Desktop/Test/test2.py", line 14, in mp3_to_wav
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_file_name)

  File "C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 716, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)

  File "C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 665, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file)

  File "C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 263, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

  File "C:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

The last line is in german and means 'The system can't find the specified file'.

I read alot in a lot of forums, but i could not find any solution. Im kinda new in programming in Python (and programming in generell) and I have no idea what I have to do. Would be great if anyone could help.

Comment: Try two slashes: `"C://Users//Linus//Desktop//Test//Audio/"`

Comment: I already tried that, but thanks for you'r help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich glaube, dass Sie FFMPEG nicht installiert haben. Mach mal `pip install ffmpeg` und dann entweder schreiben Sie das in deinem PATH oder in Ihrem Programm: `AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "C:\\path\\path\\ffmpeg.exe"` (das ist wo Sie FFMPEG installiert haben)
Ich lerne gerade Deutsch, also sorry wenn ich etwas flasch geschrieben habe :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your awnser. 

I installed FFMPEG (checked it in my cmd) and added it to the PATH. But i stil got the warning and my programm don't work. 
I even add it to the programm but still got the warning.

Ach und dein Deutsch ist sehr gut :)

Comment: It's me again :) I found my mistake. I add FFMPEG into my user PATH. After i added it into my system PATH aswell it worked. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Könnten Sie bitte mir einen Up-Vote geben? :)